# CSS : How to make two column right fluid left fluid depend on right

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, fluid-dynamics

I already search and there is no exactly solution for me. I am trying to making Two Columns:

> Left fluid + Right fluid.

Left column is contain input box with 100% `width` and the left column `width` is depend on right column `width`.

- B is just a text div but I don't know a text's length. It is dynamic length.
- A is just input box.

So if B is longer text, A should be shorter.

*Please take look at the below image*

[image: Please take look at the below image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: thanks you so much and sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` and just set `flex: 1` on input.

```css
.el {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
  background: #A3FF9A;
}
p {
  background: #FF87DE;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
  <input type="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @pors instead of saying thank you please consider an upvote and accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Site name</title>
    </head>
<style>
        #container{
         width: 900px;
    }
    #container:after{clear: both; display: table; content: "";}
    #container:before{ display: table; content: "";}
    .left-column{
        width: 400px;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px; 
        background: green;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .left-column input{width: 100%;}
    .right-column{
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 500px;
        background: violet;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
<body>
   <div id="container"> 
       <div class="left-column">
           <input name="f-name" type="text"></input>
       </div>
       <div class="right-column">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
           adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
           incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
           Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
           exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
           aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis 
           aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
           voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
           fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
           occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
           in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
           anim id est laborum.
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```